# Why am I getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined'?

Tags: asp.net, typescript, model-view-controller, angular5

I am working on a small project.  It is an ASP.NET MVC/Angular5 project. I am simply trying to populate a tableView (PrimeNG) with data that is selected from a Modal or PrimeNG Dialog.

Here is a snipit of the relevent ts file:

```
 displayIndexDialog: boolean;
  index: Index = {};
  selectedIndex: Index;
  newIndex: boolean;
  indexes: Index[];
//METHODS
 getIndexes() {
    this._indexesService.getIndexes().subscribe(indexes => this.indexList = indexes);

  }
showIndexAdd() {
    this.newIndex = true;
    this.selectedIndex = {};
    this.displayIndexDialog = true;
    this.getIndexes();

  }
closeIndexDialog() {
    this.displayIndexDialog = false;
  }
 saveIndex() {
    let index = [...this.indexes];

    if (this.newIndex) {
      index.push(this.index);
    }else
      index[this.indexes.indexOf(this.selectedIndex)] = this.index;

    this.indexes = index;
    this.indexes = null;
    this.displayIndexDialog = false;
  };
//INTERFACE
interface Index {
  defaultIndex?;
  pK_Index ?;
  description ?;
}
```

Here is the relevent HTML:

```
<!--INDEX TABLE-->
<p-table [columns]="cols3" [value]="indexes">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
              <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{col.header}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
              <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
              <div style="text-align:left">
                <button class="btn-cblt" type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" (click)="showIndexAdd()" label="Add"></button>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-table><br />
          <h4>Differentials</h4>
          <p-table [columns]="cols2" [value]="diffs1">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
              <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{col.header}}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
              <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
              <div style="text-align:left">
                <button class="btn-cblt" type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" (click)="showDifferentialAdd()" label="Add"></button>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-table>

<!--ADD INDEX DIALOG-->
<p-dialog class="sha" header="Add Index" [(visible)]="displayIndexDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" [width]="600" [height]="300">
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" *ngIf="selectedIndex">
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <div class="ui-g-4">
        <label for="Index">Index</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-8">
        <p-dropdown id="index" placeholder="Select an Index" [options]="indexList" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndex.description" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" optionLabel="description" [showClear]="true"> </p-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <div class="ui-g-4">
        <label for="isDefault">Default Index?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-8">
        <p-checkbox name="defaultIndex" id="isDefault"  [(ngModel)]="selectedIndex.defaultIndex"></p-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="indexName">{{index.pK_Index ? index.pK_Index: ' ' }}</div>
  </div>

    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-helper-clearfix">
      <button class="btn-cblt" type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" (click)="saveIndex()" label="Save"></button>
      <button class="btn-cblt-danger" type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="closeIndexDialog()" label="Cancel"></button>
    </div>

</p-dialog>
```

Every time I click the 'save' button on the dialog, in the console I get:

﻿[image: CHROME CONSOLE LOG]

I have been staring at this for 3 days now and Have no idea why this isn't working. Please help!

Comment: It could be because `indexes` is not initialized. Try `indexes: Index[] = []`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that did seem to remove the original error. So thank you for that. Ultimately I am wanting that object to hold data from the Modal and pas it back to the table on the page. The object just remains a blank object now. Oh well, as far as the original question I guess it is resolved. Thank you and I will close this question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Resolution to this was @ConnorsFan 's suggestion. The `indexes` were not initialized. Setting `indexes: Index[] = []` fixed the issue. Thank you @ConnorsFan.